# How do I find the Subresource Integrity (SRI) code for the debug version of bootstrap 5?

Tags: bootstrap-5, cdn, jsdelivr

Bootstrap 5.3.0-alpha3 is hosted on JsDelivr network. I can see that on this link https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/bootstrap?tab=stats

I can right click the copy icon and copy the SRI code for the minified version. But where do I find the SRI code for the non-minified/debug version of the resource?

This is the minified version
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js

This is the un-minified version.
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using an SRI Hash generator like https://www.srihash.org